# Submitting 2 forms separately via AJAX - Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to submit 2 separate forms via AJAX, but on submitting form2 I get a 500 bad request error.
My HTML code is below, but basically my page is a flask template that works as follows:

*User makes selections

*These selections are then posted via the submit button named "button" Value "Calculate Available Overall Heights".

*This runs some SQL query to determine a list of entries that are placed into a newly generated `<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()"></select>`
This is done by JS which is also listed below as MyJS.js

> OAH.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>

      <p class="h2">XXX</p>
      <form method="post" id="form1">
        <fieldset>
      </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">




<span style="float:left"><label>Overall Height</label></span>
              ///my inputs, various selects etc ///

            <div id="response">
              <!-- Empty element until form submitted-->
            </div>

            <p id="ApertureHeight"></p>
            <p id="ApertureHeightBelowPelmet"></p>
            <p id="ApertureHeightUnderRoofSticks"></p><br>
            <p id="OverallWidth"></p>
            <p id="RearAppWidth"></p>
            <p id="RearPillarNS"></p>
            <p id="OAH"></p>

      </div>
        </fieldset>
      <script src="/static/js/MyJS.js"></script>

      </form>

        <form method="post" id="form2">


          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label>
                  <span style="float:left"><input type="text" id="myText" value=""></span>
                       </label>
              <br>
        <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />

          </div>
          </form>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

form2 has a button called "Click Me!" which calls a function that submits form 2.

`submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
};`

> MyJS.js

```
    $("#form1").on("submit", function(event) {
  $targetElement = $('#response');
  event.preventDefault();
  // Perform ajax call
  //
  console.log("Sending data: " + $(this).serialize());
  $.ajax({
    url: '/OAH',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      // Success handler
      var TableTing = response["table"];
      $("#TableThing").empty();
      $("#TableThing").append(TableTing);
      for (key in response) {
        if (key == 'myList') {
          // Add the new elements from 'myList' to the form
          $targetElement.empty();
          select = $('<select id="mySelect" class="form-control" onchange="myFunction()"></select>');

          response[key].forEach(function(item) {
            select.append($('<option>').text(item));
          });
          $targetElement.html(select);
        } else {
          // Update existing controls to those of the response.
          $(':input[name="' + key + '"]').val(response[key]);
        }
      }
      return myFunction()
      // End handler
    }
    // Proceed with normal submission or new ajax call
  })
});



submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$("#form2").on("submit", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Sending data: " + $(this).serialize());
  $.ajax({
    url: '/OAH',
    data: $('#form2').serialize(),
    datatype: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
      return myFunction()
      // End handler
    }
    // Proceed with normal submission or new ajax call
  })
});
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function myFunction() {
  var FifthWheel = document.getElementById("FifthWheelHeight").value;
  var NeckDepth = document.getElementById("NeckDepth").value;
  var CantRailDepth = document.getElementById("CantRailDepth").value;
  var RearTensioner = document.getElementById("RearTensioner").value;
  var OAH = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  if (CantRailDepth = 115) {
    var PelmetDim = 100;
  } else {
    PelmetDim = 75;
  }
  var ApertureHeight = Number(OAH) - Number(FifthWheel) - Number(NeckDepth) - Number(CantRailDepth);
  var ApertureHeightBelowPelment = Number(ApertureHeight) - Number(PelmetDim);
  var ApertureHeightUnderRoofSticks = Number(OAH) - Number(FifthWheel) - Number(NeckDepth) - 35;

  document.getElementById("ApertureHeight").innerHTML = "Aperture below Cantrail = " + ApertureHeight + "mm";
  document.getElementById("ApertureHeightBelowPelmet").innerHTML = "Aperture below pelmet = " +
    ApertureHeightBelowPelment + "mm";
  document.getElementById("ApertureHeightUnderRoofSticks").innerHTML = "Aperture below roof sticks = " +
    ApertureHeightUnderRoofSticks + "mm";
  document.getElementById("OverallWidth").innerHTML = "Overall Width = 2548mm (2550mm on spec)";
  document.getElementById("OAH").innerHTML = OAH;
  document.getElementById("myText").value = document.getElementById("OAH").innerHTML;
}
```

I need this form to submit separately, via AJAX without refreshing the page, as I need the JSON array to be able to calculate further stuff that will be passed into Python Flask. My issue is I am getting a bad request when submitting form2.

Anyone got any ideas on what I have done wrong?

Comment: It's hard to know if the problem is in your client side JS or on the server side. You should try use PostMan to test the server side with the data that you expect to work, then mimic that with JS. Also use the Network tab of the developer tools in Chrome/etc to inspect the Request Headers.

Comment: yeah it's still struggling. Network tab just says 400 error. 
I'm wondering if it's possible to post separate values to JSON, or even if there is another easy way of getting the data from the text box or select box out and stored somewhere that a flask GET request can get to? 
It'd be handy if, there was a button that you press and it takes all the values from each input and stores it as a text file on the server?

Comment: Well 400 is different from 500 error. 400 is bad request which means your data is being sent but it's not in the format that Python is expecting. Could you post the GET handler for submitting form2? Just noticed also... you're posting to the same URL in form2 ajax as in form1, is that correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, both forms are on the same URL /OAH. I basically want it to just post the data that's attached to form2 to JSON array. Is what I've done wrong or is there a better way to achieve? Appreciate your assistance, I'm learning still!

Comment: How is form1 populated and submitted? You have `$("#form1").on("submit",` but I don't see any way that this form can be submitted?

Comment: Sorry, it had been removed when I was trying to shorten. 
It's submitted by a button
<input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="button" name="button" type="submit" value=
        "Calculate Available Overall Heights">

Comment: So form1 is there just for the purpose of _loading_ values then?

Comment: https://hack.chat/?dcsohelp123 join this for a quick chat

Comment: Yeah, it has a separate "Response" div that gets populated by inputs that you've selected, it fills in a select entry and I need to get the value of that select entry somehow into Flask. I was trying to do this by getting my form2 to just look at the value of the select, then post that. But there may be another simpler way, i'm sure.

Comment: Your issue may be partially due to your `data` field in your 2 ajax calls. Handler for form 1 has `data: $('form').serialize()` and form 2 has `data: $('#form2').serialize()`. Unless of course this was intentional for some reason.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I have changed that to `data: $('#form1').serialize(),` but still get the issue of 400 bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the same endpoint URL to try handle 2 different requests. The 2nd form does not send the correct data and you're then getting Server errors. Try creating another endpoint on your python flask server for handling form2 and the `myText` field value.